# Unable to Segue after re-launching application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, oauth

I have an iOS (iPad) application i am working on that needs to do OAuth with Twitter.

At the moment i have it launching Safari (Using STTwitter), where the users logs into twitter and authorises the app. I then have a callback that re-activates the app and passes the tokens.

This works as expected.

However, i would like to Segue to a new VC, when the app re-activates. However for some reason i am unable to call any Segues manually once the app has restarted, it just crashes complaining that the requested Segue is not available.

I am able to Segue using an object fine. And if i bypass the callout code so the app doesn't close then the Segue runs fine.

I'm guessing the View Controller is being unloaded from memory somehow, even though it's still visible when the app comes back up.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Gareth

**Edit 1 - Added Code**

Here is the code being called. This actually seems to be an issue where all code called Seguays after the app has been relaunched do not work. However opens connected to an object do.

```
- (void)UploadSuccess{

    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"approveSeguay" sender:self];

}
```

which is being called in the View Controller from this method in the AppDelegate

```
- (void)postToTwitter:(NSString*)postText image:(UIImage*)image{

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

[_twitter postStatusUpdate:postText
            mediaDataArray:@[data]
         possiblySensitive:nil
         inReplyToStatusID:nil
                  latitude:nil
                 longitude:nil
                   placeID:nil
        displayCoordinates:nil
       uploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

       } successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {

           ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
           [vc uploadSuccess];

       } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

           ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
           [vc uploadFail:error];

       }];



}
```

I have also tried this, which also does nothing:

```
- (void)UploadSuccess{

    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewPhoto"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

They're all getting hit if i set breakpoints, and nothing is logged error wise.

Thanks!

Gareth

Comment: Can you put the code up from when you're returning via the callback and perform segue.

Comment: Hi Michael, code added.

Comment: Please put the whole method up in which the performSegue is :)

Comment: Is there any reason you're connecting to Twitter via OAuth and not using the SocialKit Framework? It's much easier

Comment: Yes, this is an application for a user to temporarily authenticate to the app to upload a photo, then the credentials are trashed. So using the built-in account wouldn't really work. Will upload code shortly.

Comment: Have added some more code to show what i'm doing, i'm a bit lost on this one as it all the code controlled Seguay seems to completely fail from the point when the app is re-launched.